# Android repeated ringing with Notification manager

Tags: android, android-notifications

```
public class test extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test);

        String extra = "test";

        NotificationManager myNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, another.class);

        Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, extra, 
                System.currentTimeMillis());
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 
                0,
                intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        notification.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), "title", "text", pendingIntent);


        notification.defaults|= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
        notification.defaults|= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
        notification.defaults|= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT;
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        myNotificationManager.notify(1, notification);
    }
}
```

This snippet code is working fine, the thing is that, when I run it,  the notification sound is ringing constantly until i check it on the status bar. 
Is there a way to make it ring only one time, instead of constantly ringing ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove the flag `Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT`

From docs: "Bit to be bitwise-ored into the flags field that if set, the audio will be repeated until the notification is cancelled or the notification window is opened."